# Exporting Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, crystal-reports

Alright, I've been racking my brain for days here. I have a VB.NET Web Application using Crystal Reports. Its been running smoothly until I moved it to a new server.

The problem is, when I try to export the report, this shows up at the bottom of the page and won't prompt the save dialog box.

Any ideas is sincerely appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Crystal Reports]

Comment: What is the export format you use? This probably has something to do with Mime types in IIS...

Comment: @user1429080 PDF. I have a function that lets the user select what format the report should be exported in, but it results into the same scenario.

`ExportToHttpResponse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me days to troubleshoot. As it turns out, Crystal Report for 32bit and 64bit was installed on the server. Just had to uninstall 32bit and disable the `Enable 32bit Applications` option for the Application Pool.

Just in case someone stumbles upon here with the same predicament. :)